# How to mimic leaflet default panel buttons

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working on a leaflet application and would like to mimic the default draw control panel buttons to move them to a more convient location on my application.  The icons in question being these [image]

I can see the objects within the drawcontrol I just don't know how to invoke these methods

Thanks so much

Comment: What do you mean by minic ?

Comment: replicate the function completely from a different source, for example the draw a marker button executes a drop marker on x,y function. Ideally, I would want this and the other functions to be called from a nav-bar of sorts and hide the on-map draw control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the primary call looks like so

`this.polyline.enable();` for the draw functions, meaning that marker would look like
`this.marker.enable();`

defined as

`this.polyline = new L.Draw.Polyline(this.map, { shapeOptions: { color: 'green' } });
this.marker = new L.Draw.Marker(this.map, {icon: new mark()});`

same goes with the other polys to add to the map, zoom-in/out is also `this.map.zoomIn; this.map.zoomOut` respectively